# Search for all pictures except in x directory

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I am searching for "Camera:T2i" to find all of the pictures on my hard drive from my DSLR. Is there a way to exclude a certain directory (the one that I am moving them all to). That folder is very large and very sorted so I cant just move it somewhere or cut and paste everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to a post on microsoft web site:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-tms/how-do-exclude-folders-from-windows-search/58f845f6-d6fa-449e-a921-52be453038f1?msgId=39420471-59be-4b1e-9c03-8168e808c814

> To exclude a specific folder’s contents, along with subfolders and
>   their contents, the path to that folder can be specified with a minus
>   sign as in this example syntax:
>
> -folder:(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chart graphing)

Modify paste the following into windows search:
There are intentional space between search terms.
Works on Windows 7 just tested it.

cameramake:sony cameramodel:DSC-R1 -folder:(c:\x)